# Using a ttf file in css

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

To my knowledge to use a custom font, stored locally in this case, you would use something similar to this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'theFontFamily';
    src local('the font'),
        local('the-font'),
        url(path/to/the-font);
}

.fontClass {
    font-family: 'theFontFamily', extra_settings;
}
```

So using this [font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico?selection.family=Pacifico), locally, would you expect this to work?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'),
       local('Pacifico-Regular'),
       url(resources/fonts/Pacifico.ttf);
}

.logo-container {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
```

As when I try it, the code changes the font, just not to the desired font. It looks like this.

[image]

Whereas if I use the import link, `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">`, just using the following code works.

```
.logo-container {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
```

This looks like this.

[image]

I have probably made a simple mistake and I would appreciate if someone would be able to aid me in fixing this.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right url? The reason the font still looks different locally is because `cursive` is loaded instead of `'Pacifico'` since it can't be found

Comment: @Bubblesphere I believe this is the problem. Just finding the right url now as the one I have should work. And latest version of google chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you link the source url properly. Try

```
 @font-face {

   font-family: 'myPacifico' ;
   src: url('/resources/fonts/Placifico.ttf') format('truetype');

}
```

That's basic enough, then to use...
     .logo-container {

```
     font-family: 'myPacifico', san-serif;      }
```

San-serif in this case is a fallback. In this case, ive linked to the regular ttf file. For bold and other styles, u'ld have to link to that in another @font-face with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work (tricky to say for sure without being able to test 100%):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  src: url('Pacifico-Regular.eot');
  src: url('Pacifico-Regular.eot?#iefix')
       url('Pacifico-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Pacifico-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Pacifico-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('Pacifico-Regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

To just use the TrueType font locally:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  src: url('Pacifico-Regular.ttf');
}
```

Bear in mind you should have more than just the TrueType font for the highest level of browser compatibility, but for testing with just TTF you can delete any lines not referring to the TTF version.

Comment: Unfortunately when you click download on google fonts, at least in this case, only the `.ttf` is downloaded.

Comment: I believe the download is intended so that you're able to use the font locally, like in Photoshop and Illustrator. You can delete all lines except the TTF line, just be aware you'll get spotty browser support with just the TTF.

Comment: Which browser are you testing on?